# How to remove custom font settings in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I work with my own and client websites as part of my marketing services. Mainly, I want to see all websites the way they were designed to be seen.

Chrome seems to force me to choose font settings, but I don't want my preferred font settings - I want to see the fonts chosen by the webmaster for that given website. I.e. if they used Arial, I don't want to see Tahoma.

How do I get rid of custom font settings in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Every browser, (including Internet Explorer 6) has default font settings.
For example, on Firefox is in option, content. (third tab)

This is for when the webmaster did not set a font on the page.

Some browsers just offer no choice, have prefefined fonts for the page.

Chrome won't replace any font websites.

What maybe you have got is a problem when you install "complex" fonts like Helvetica neue with all of its 51 variants on Windows - font rendering will change a lot in browsers.

Comment: Appreciate the input. But, I have to disagree. Im on chrome and viewing 3 sites that I personally designed. And, factually can say they are all "google" fonts. Yet, the fonts do not appear in chrome as they are written in the css on the actual website. I go to chrome "advanced" settings and can manipulate the font setting to match the website... but my issue is, why should I have to? And, when I do, the other websites I visit now are viewed with the new font settings.This is all new to me. Is it new to chrome? I don't want custom fonts. I just want what the website has intended visitors to see

Comment: I never seen a such problem. Maybe you enabled some accessibility feature?